# Contact picker namespace for windows 8 phone app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am not able to use contact picker in my windows 8 phone app.

The windows.applicationmodel namespace does not have contacts.

I am using visual studio express edition 2012 .

Comment: not able is not a good description of your problem

Comment: What class did you try to use? There is no such thing like contact chooser in WP.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone 8 does not have the [`ContactPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactpicker.aspx) class - you're thinking Windows 8. For a Windows Phone-specific way to access contact information, read [this official article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286414%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).